# creating re-usable django library

Tags: python, django, package

I am new to django. I want to create a library using django which i can use in multiple projects. This library when imported must must provide functions which can be used in other projects. I have read the documentation of django but according to it the way to interact with library created using django is via urls. 
      How to expose the functions of my library which can be used in other projects? Eg. If I create a library say, calculator, I want to provide functions like add, subtract. Thanks.

Comment: You question is very generic and therefor hard to answer. Can you get more specific?

Comment: In django the urls provided in urls.py file are way by which we can interact with the functionality by in my case i don't want to expose the urls, i just want to expose the functions, @WhoKnows has given some direction, thanks

Comment: "I have read the documentation of django but according to it the way to interact with library created using django is via urls" => err, I'm afraid you didn't quite understand the doc then. Please post a link to the exact part of the doc where you found this.

Comment: And the answer to your question is:  just write your "library" (whether a django app or a simple python package or module), install it in place where Python can find it, and import the functions, classes or whatever you want. Unless your library provides specificly django stuff (models, custom templatetags/filters etc), all you need is a pure Python module or package (django apps are actually Python packages but with a specific layout and they are treated specially by django at startup).

Comment: Thanks. That is illuminating!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the project itself
In the project calculator, you can have file with methods (add,subtract,.. called  `ops`

So in you new project foo you can do something like:

```
from calculator import ops 
foo = ops.add(5,6)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that you can use GIT for your purpose. Create REPO on GITHUB of your app separately from other your projects. And then you can do

```
>>> pip install git+https://github.com/yournickname/your-repo.git
```

At the same time your REPO could be local(offline) and you can make installation via pip directly from the folder on your development machine.

```
>>> pip install /opt/your-repo
```